# Yii2 - search params with link

Tags: search, parameters, yii2, pjax

i need implement a search by attribute “year”, but i need this in links (ex. when i click in link “2017”, $dataProvider return only records with “year” = “2017”), in index..php i have:

```
<div class="y-index">

    <?php echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Oficios Apqe'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>

<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
                'id',
                'name',
                'minuta',
                'year',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>

</div>
```

**_search.php**

```
<div class="y-search">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['index'],
        'method' => 'get',
    ]); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'id') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'name') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'minuta') ?>

<?= Html::a('2019', ['index', 'year' => '2019'], ['class' => 'year label label-efault', 'id' => '2019']) ; ?>
<?= Html::a('2018', ['index', 'year' => '2018'], ['class' => 'year label label-default', 'id' => '2018']) ; ?>
<?= Html::a('2017', ['index', 'year' => '2017'], ['class' => 'year label label-default', 'id' => '2017']) ; ?>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Search'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Reset'), [Yii::$app->controller->action->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

basically i need the example with site from yii:

[image]

when i click in left menu in "Tutorial" option the link is set "https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki?category=3&version=2.0";

[image]
and after when i click in me menu "AJAX", the link is append and set to "https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki?tag=ajax&category=3&version=2.0";

[image]

basiclly i need search form param "year" with link, and with concatenate params from form "_search.php".

Comment: add your view along with the form you are using

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i edited the question and add view and form.

Comment: added an answer see if that helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

### You can pass an array as the second parameter.

`Html::a()` uses `yii\helpers\Url::to()` on the background to create the link, [docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#a()-detail). You can use any parameters that you want passing them as an array.

```
Html::a(
    '2017', 
    ['', 'year' => '2017'], 
    ['class' => 'year label label-default', 'id' => '2017']
) ;
```

Comment: the problem is, how to combine this with the `_search` form, when I use this form I lose the parameters passed in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the `action` from the `_search.php` form it would submit to the current action automatically, and it would append the current query string with the new search parameters passed from the form.

Just change the

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
     'action' => ['index'],
     'method' => 'get',
]); ?>
```

to

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
     'method' => 'get',
]); ?>
```

Comment: if I first click on the link with the "year" and then submit the search form with other parms (eg "name"), it works correctly. (append the current query string with the new search parameters passed from the form.)
But if I first search with another param (eg "name"), submit, and after click on the link "year", the url clean all params and gets only `controller/action?year=2019`

Comment: @Moutinho i dont think that would be possible and that was not the original question  asked by you, and above all it does makes sense that the url is overwritten when you click on the link which points to `year` only

Comment: is it not possible with a click (label, link, button or other) to add search params to what already exists in the url?

Comment: How does sorting work? it always adds the param `&sort=attribute` to the existing url..